# Compatible browser for redhat

Tags: firefox, browser, redhat

I want to install firefox on Linux without admin rights in my local memroy space.Is is possible to install it without admin rights? I am using rhel 4. I had already tried it via extracting .tar.bz2.But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 4 reached end of life back in 2012, although it is still barely hanging on with Extended Life Cycle Support until next year.  Because of the age of the operating system it's not going to be possible to use a recent version of Firefox with it.

Comment: Yes,That's true,Agreed.But Which previous version of firefox it supports at Max?